# Samsung Galaxy S2 Settings Notifications crash

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2. In my notifications, the "Configuration Message List" is always highlighted, but pressing it causes the phone to exit to the home screen. All other notifications work.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I solved this by going into the "Active Applications" widget, and clearing the memory through the RAM - section.

Answer (score 1):

I rebooted the device and the message was gone.

Comment: Rebooting is generally the best option in such cases where the system is stuck on to a few things / memory not cleared or so.